# How do I install the following files when I already have WordPress installed on my server?

Tags: wordpress, installation

How do I install the following files when I already have WordPress installed on my server? The developer gave me a folder that has the WordPress core files and then there is a .sql file that I don't know what to do with. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First: are you just trying to get a theme installed on your WP environment or are you trying to replicate everything that the developer before had set up?

If the answer is full replication - what's your level of understating with phpMyAdmin? If the answer is "limited" then I'd advise pulling in a developer to take this project on as it'll need some skill with phpMyAdmin. They should know what to do with the files & have the ability to get that existing data (the .sql) file in to the right place - doing it yourself could have some unintended results (wiping out all your data)